# Adaptive MCMC for discrete random variables

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

Let {$Y_1,Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$} be a sequence of random variables where $Y_t$ follows a multinomial distribution with $n=1$ (the number of trials) and $\pi_t = (\pi_{t1}, \pi_{t2}, \cdots, \pi_{tk})'$ be the probability vector. The probability vector $\pi_t$ is modelled as:
$$
\mathrm{logit} \pi_t = W + A(x_{t-1} -\pi_{t-1}) + B\mathrm{logit} \pi_{t-1}
$$
where $A, B:(k-1)\times(k-1), \,\,W:(k-1)\times1.$ Let $\theta = (W, A, B)$ be the vector of the unknown parameters.

My goal is to draw a sample of the posterior distribution using an adaptive MCMC method. I read the paper "Examples of Adaptive MCMC, Roberts and Rosenthal (2008)" and used the Adaptive Metropolis algorithm.

My question is: Is it valid to use this algorithm? I had a conversation with someone who told me that the algorithm has been tested for Normal data and maybe it is not a good choice because my data are discrete.

Comment: The conditions set in that paper do not assume normality on the data. Furthermore, you plan to simulate according to a continuous distribution on the parameters, so there is nothing discrete in the simulation or the target.